# SQL: retrieving CSV from within a View using a Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I started off with the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209037/sql-listing-many-to-many-from-single-query).

I decided I wanted to retrieve the information (users, CSV roles for each user) from a view.  The view didn't like the syntax of the WITH/FOR XML and so I decided to put that piece in a Function.

The view looks something like this:

```
SELECT u.UserId, u.UserName, dbo.GetRolesCsvFromUserId(u.UserId)
FROM Users u
```

I was successful up to the point of removing the trailing comma.  Here's the function.  How do i remove the trailing comma from within this function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRolesCsvFromUserId] (@UserId int)
RETURNS nvarchar(100) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN
    (
        SELECT r.RoleName + ',' AS 'data()'
        FROM Roles r INNER JOIN UsersInRoles ur ON ur.RoleId = r.RoleId
        WHERE ur.UserId = @UserId FOR XML PATH('')
    )
END
```

Comment: Maybe you should read the next highest voted answer for that question...

Comment: @OMG Ponies, I tried to get your solution to work, but no luck.  I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it - which is why I went with the highest voted answer.  I again spent the last 20 minutes trying to get it working, but without any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @OMG Ponies pointed out, his solution solves your problem without needing a function. Still, if you need to create a function, you can do it without the `XML PATH`. Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRolesCsvFromUserId] (@UserId int)
RETURNS nvarchar(100) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Return nvarchar(100)
    SET @Return = ''

    SELECT @Return = @Return + r.RoleName + ','
    FROM Roles r INNER JOIN UsersInRoles ur ON ur.RoleId = r.RoleId
    WHERE ur.UserId = @UserId

    SET @Return = LEFT(@Return,LEN(@Return)-1)

    RETURN
    (
        @Return
    )
END
```

Comment: Works great - thx.  Just added the length check prior to the removal of the trailing comma.